# What improvements will Axiom Space's Artemis spacesuit bring to current EMUs?

Tags: spacesuits, artemis-program, moonwalking

We know a design focus of the [Axiom Extravehicular Mobility Unit (AxEMU)](https://www.space.com/artemis-moon-spacesuit-axiom-space-milestone-aim) is to offer more flexibility for size fitting and movement than current EMUs, both for spacewalks and moonwalks.

Based on what we have seen from their [livestreams](https://www.nasa.gov/humans-in-space/spacesuit-for-nasas-artemis-iii-moon-surface-mission-debuts/) and know from recent news, how is Axiom Space accomplishing this? And are there other improvements being made?

Comment: related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63107/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-axemu-and-xemu

Comment: @ErinAnne I have seen your post. I'm not really asking for technical details though (doubt anyone would be able or willing to answer). A more general answer concerning their design goals and overall steps to accomplish them would more than suffice :)